# Rearranging divs between desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a site but want to rearrange the order of the items on the page depending on whether it is on desktop or mobile.

So for desktop it is something like this:

[image]

And then for mobile I want to do something like:

[image]

All these items are their own divs, I just want a way to rearrange them.

### Edit

This is really simplified everything is being generated by PHP.

My HTML at present is like so:

```
<div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="search"></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="Menu1"></ul>
        <ul id="Menu2"></ul>
        <ul id="Menu2"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want it to be something like:

```
<div>
    <ul id="Menu1"></ul>    
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <ul id="Menu3"></ul>
    <div id="search"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add you html code

Comment: You could use Javascript/jQuery to render that part on body load.

Comment: Sounds like a job for media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries if it's just a layout change.

Comment: @DBS Or that :) This way you can use the CSS attribute **position** to specify the locations.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I love how there are hundreds of ways to do this. a simple .hide() and .show() in jQuery is peanuts.

Comment: As I see in your earlier question you know how to use media-query :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200052/css-js-jquery-flex-items-for-responsive-screen-sizes

Comment: I meant with a media query, but that would work too :)

Comment: Yeah so they are going to be styled differently with media queries in the CSS, what I'm actually looking for is a way to rearrange the order of the divs in the actual HTML

Comment: You can use `flex` and `order` for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property

Comment: Do you actually need to rearrange the structure? You can do that with JS, but it will be significantly slower and doesn't really achieve anything that can't be done with CSS (At least in terms of layout) Are you actually solving a different problem and have over-simplified it for this question?

Comment: That is the purpose of css display `grid` used with media queries.

Comment: Where did Menu 2 go on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my cases, I have two options to solve this problem. 
1. Render both mobile and desktop version and shows only one at a time. This is somehow a fast solution but not a professional way. 
2. Using jquery or javascript. 
so I assume that every div knows its order for both mobile and desktop cases. 
and every divs width for both mobile and desktop are defined in CSS.

 let's define a div like this for example

```
<div id="menu1" data-desktop-order="2" data-mobile-order="0"> Menu1 </div>
<div id="search-bar" data-desktop-order="1" data-mobile-order="3"> Search Bar </div> 
...
```

and in resize event or documentReady reorder the divs

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight <= 767) { /* Reorder divs for mobile cases */ }        
    if (window.innerWidth > 767) {  /* Reorder divs for desktop cases */ }
}
```

For reordering divs, you can reference below links. 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table